# Question about the Java documentation and its implementation

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm currently sitting at an exercise, which wants me to create a Java program based on an already finished documentation HTML sheet.
For example, one entry states

> ## reversedArray
>
> ```
> public static Object[] reversedArray(Object[] array)
> ```

Based on the name, we can assume the method should return an array in the reversed order of `array`.

Now my question isn't about how to create the said array, but more about the `Object[]` terminology. What does it mean? Should I create a bunch of methods through overloading each with a specific array type (e.g. `String[]`, `int[]`, ...) or literally an `Object[]`?

It's the latter, how does an object array work? Based on the name, I assume it's an array that can hold objects, but I'm unsure what this means in practice.

Comment: " I should create a bunch of methods through overloading each with a specific array type". No, you only have to create overloads for the primitive types i.e. `int[]`, `long[]` etc and that's only if your requirement says so. the aforementioned method  should be able to consume`String[]` , `Integer[]` , `Double[]` etc...

Comment: "As the name already states, the method should create a new array" what makes you think so? It could also reverse array passed as argument and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object[]` is basically just an array of objects (best explanation award right here please ----> ☐ )

Jokes aside, in Java, any object is derived from the class `Object` so basically, this array can store any object of any class. It's mostly useful when you just want to carry an instance (or several instances) of different classes, but the type of said instance is not important.

Let's say you have multiple classes that are not necessarily related :

```
Class Dog {
    String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Hello! I am a dog called " + this.name;
    }
}
```

---

```
Class Refrigerator {
    public Refrigerator() {
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "I am a refrigerator";
    }
}
```

Since both classes are implicitly derived from `Object` and that `Object` implements the method `toString()` you can override that method in both of you class declarations.

Then you can store any instance of these in a `Object` and call the method `toString()`, like so :

```
Dog myDog = new Dog("Spike");
Object anyObject = myDog;
System.out.println(anyObject.toString());   //would print the result of your "toString()" method in the Dog class : 
                                            //"Hello! I am a dog called Spike"


Refrigerator myFridge = new Refrigerator();
Object secondObject = myFridge;
System.out.println(secondObject.toString());    //would print the result of your "toString()" method in the Refrigerator class : 
                                                //"I am a refrigerator"
```

This allows you to create a method that accepts any object and treats them the same and assign any object in argument :

```
public void printWhatYouAre(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}

public void doingSomething() {
    Dog myDog = new Dog("Spike");
    Refrigerator myFridge = new Refrigerator();

    printWhatYouAre(myDog);
    printWhatYouAre(myFridge); //would print the same as above
}
```

---

In your case, your method only needs to rearrange an array, which means it doesn't even need the method toString nor does it need to know what the objects are. It just needs to store an array of something into an other array of something in a different order.

---

[Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java) is a nice reading about polymorphism in Java, which is basically applicable in any language, but the examples that are used are wrote in Java. [The whole site](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial) actually is a pretty good reference, so it's worth taking a look, especially the OOP sections which are the most related to your post. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> As the name already states, the method should create a new array in
>   the reversed order of "array".

The method name only says to "reverse" the array; whether it's just a matter of modifying the actually supplied array or constructing a new one is something you'll need to clarify with the author of the requirement if it's not clear.

> Now my question isn't about how to create said array, but more about
>   the "Object[]" terminology. Basically, I'm unsure what to do. Does
>   said "Object[]" mean, I should create a bunch of methods through
>   overloading each with a specific array type (e.g. String[], int[],...)
>   or literally an Object[] array?

No, you only have to create overloads for the primitive types i.e. `int[]`, `long[]` etc and that's only if your requirement says so. the aforementioned method should be able to consume `Object[]`, `String[]` , `Integer[]` , `Double[]` etc...

> It it's the latter, how does an object array work? Based on the name I
>   assume, it's an array that can hold objects, but I'm unsure what this
>   means in practice.

The method name has nothing to do with what an array can hold, the method argument is an array of `Object`'s and it's as simple as that.

Reading you might find useful:

- [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)